# Autocomplete mysql query taking long

Tags: mysql

I have query like this:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE
           WHEN text LIKE 'harv' THEN 1
           WHEN text LIKE 'harv%' THEN 2
           WHEN text LIKE '%harv%' THEN 3
       END AS priority
FROM
  ( SELECT b.bschool_name AS `text`,
           'bschool' AS `type`,
           b.slug AS `id`,
           n.neighbourhood AS 'params'
   FROM bschool b
   LEFT JOIN bschool_addresses ba ON (b.id=ba.bschool_id)
   LEFT JOIN neighbourhoods n ON (ba.neighbourhood_id=n.id)
   WHERE b.entity_status = 'active'
     AND ba.city_id='13'
   UNION SELECT tg.option AS `text`,
                'tags' AS `type`,
                tg.option AS `id`,
                tg.option AS 'params'
   FROM tags t
   LEFT JOIN tag_options tg ON (t.id=tg.tag_id)
   WHERE t.tag='MBA'
   UNION SELECT category AS `text`,
                'category' AS `type`,
                category AS `id`,
                category AS 'params'
   FROM categories
   UNION SELECT area AS `text`,
                'area' AS `type`,
                id AS `id`,
                id AS 'params'
   FROM areas
   WHERE city_id='13'
   UNION SELECT district AS `text`,
                'districts' AS `type`,
                id AS `id`,
                id AS 'params'
   FROM districts
   WHERE city_id='13'
   UNION SELECT neighbourhood AS `text`,
                'neighbourhood' AS `type`,
                id AS `id`,
                id AS 'params'
   FROM neighbourhoods
   WHERE city_id='13' ) AS t1
WHERE `text` LIKE 'harv'
  OR `text` LIKE 'harv%'
  OR `text` LIKE '%harv%'
ORDER BY priority LIMIT 5
```

Basically this query is getting top 5 business schools that has text "harv" in it in neighbourhood 13 and also gets schools which offer MBA courses which has text "harv". This query is for autocomplete search. It is taking over 1 second which i think is very long for autocompelte. Am i doing something wrong in this query? Is there any way to optimize this.

EXPLAIN:

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    7649    Using where; Using filesort
2   DERIVED ba  ref IDX_76AE73698BAC62AF,IDX_76AE7369A89DB457   IDX_76AE73698BAC62AF    5       7458    Using where
2   DERIVED b   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   school_live.ba.business_id  1   Using where
2   DERIVED n   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   school_live.ba.neighbourhood_id 1   
3   UNION   t   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    22  Using where
3   UNION   tg  ref IDX_E204D72DBAD26311    IDX_E204D72DBAD26311    5   school_live.t.id    4   
4   UNION   categories  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5   
5   UNION   areas   ref IDX_58B0B25C8BAC62AF    IDX_58B0B25C8BAC62AF    5       5   Using where
6   UNION   districts   ref IDX_68E318DC8BAC62AF    IDX_68E318DC8BAC62AF    5       5   Using where
7   UNION   neighbourhoods  ref IDX_49F0CA178BAC62AF    IDX_49F0CA178BAC62AF    5       422 Using where
NULL    UNION RESULT    <union2,3,4,5,6,7>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: I think this subquery makes MySQL to build temporary table on harddisk. What does command `explain` says? If it does, then you may need to copy the text-matching part, `order by priority` and `limit 5` to inside of the subquery, to every select being union-ed.

Comment: And creating FULLTEXT keys on these text fields should help too.

Comment: what's the sql-server tag for?

Comment: @David162795 - What you mean by command explain says?

Comment: @Tanner - I think it was by mistake i removed it. Thanks!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html Just copy the query with prefix "explain " and run it.

Comment: You outer query is using LIKE with leading wildcards, hence cannot use a normal index. A FULLTEXT index might help, except that couldn't be used on the results of a sub query so you would need to do the check for 'harv' in each of the UNIONed queries.

Comment: @David162795 - What am i looking for in EXPLAIN query? I just ran it?

Comment: Copy it as whole to pastebin. It does not contain any company secrets, does it?

Comment: @David162795 - I added it to the question itself - No secrets :)

Comment: This is looking good. The bad things starts in outer query. Try out what we proposed, (1) move the text searching, sorting and limiting parts to every single inner query, before they get union-ed and sorted once again (2) add fulltext key to "text" field in every table

Comment: @David162795 - what do you mean by this? (2) add fulltext key to "text" field in every table. Also can you write basic answer for part (1) so i can mark that correct answer?

Comment: add FULTEXT indexing key to tags.option ; add FULTEXT indexing key to categories.category ; add FULTEXT indexing key to areas.area ; etc

Comment: If you want to use FULLTEXT indexes then you need to change from using LIKE to using MATCH. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html